# For fiction purposes, are there any reserved or non-existent top-level-domains writers can use in stories?

Tags: worldbuilding-resources, internet

I understand that it's long been a tradition in American fictional works, especially movies and TV, to use a '555' phone code for any numbers that needed to be displayed on-screen, as that prefix doesn't exist, and so there was no risk of the writers unwittingly using a real number.

As a writer of stories, my question is: Are there any similar non-existent or otherwise reserved top-level domains that I could use in a fictional context to avoid inadvertently publishing an in-use—or a 'likely-to-come-into-use'—domain?

I'm aware that TLDs are being created a lot more quickly than they were, but I didn't know if there were any specifically set aside.

As additional info, my current project is an alternate history story set in a modern-day Roman state, so I'd ideally be looking for a TLD I could crowbar into representing that in some way. I did consider `.spqr` as a sort of equivalent to `.gov`, though that's maybe a little heavy-handed setting-wise (but of course that's for me to figure out...).

I've also checked [this list at ICANN](https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt), and I can't see, for example, `.spqr` or `.rom`. I'd be cautious about using them if they're potentially available for future registration.

---

EDIT 23/Jan/17: Wow. I'd like to thank everyone who's taken the time to reply to this. I really do appreciate it, and there have been some great suggestions. I think, on balance, probably the easiest way to go is, as some have said, to simply come up with a new format for addresses, on the assumption that in my alternate history many things will be different, some subtly, some less so - so this might as well be one of them.

Even so, there have been some great ideas, and some interesting info provided. I'm still going through some of the comments as I have chance - please forgive me if I don't answer them all!

Again, thanks for taking time to offer these suggestions.

Comment: At this point of time, any organisation with an appropriate justification and money can probably register any TLD. Might be worth considering non standard *protocols* and slightly and carefully different domain *systems* instead. Does feel *vaguely* like it could belong elsewhere, but its almost bedtime so I'll let the community or other mods decide.

Comment: The canonical list of reserved TLDs is [BCP 32](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp32). Unfortunately, none of them are ideal for fiction. Perhaps you'll get better responses at [writers.se] (you can request mod migration of the question). Journeyman Geek's suggestion is a good one, if it works with your universe (i.e. anything but modern-day Earth) -- invent a new naming system that looks close enough to be familiar but is otherwise invalid, e.g. using colons instead of dots.

Comment: Thanks for handling the migrate, Journeyman Geek, and thanks for your consideration of my question. Bob, thank you - that does make sense and absent any other replies I think I'll likely end up going with that. After all, I suppose modern protocol was essentially just someone's design in the beginning, so I can always assume a different design.

Comment: This would be good on writers.stackexchange.com - I can't see how this is world building, it is about describing parts of the world / story in a way that won't cause real life issues.

Comment: @Mołot I disagree. This is about basic construction of an element of a fictional world, which is what Worldbuilding is about, only with the *additional* constraint that it mustn't cause conflicts with the superficially very similar system in the real world (which serves to establish the parameters of the question, just like how "give me a real-world-science explanation for how X could happen in my fictional world" does). [writers.se] is essentially about *how to write* at levels larger than paragraphs or thereabouts, so this would be squarely off topic there.

Comment: Actually, 555 is not reserved in any standard. Many phone companies voluntarily avoid numbers using it, but not all of them. Real phone numbers that of the form 555-*xyzw* do exist.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek great point about protocols. If all of the websites listed in the story were to (say) start with bctp:// (Bread and Circus Telecommunications Protocol) as opposed to http://, it shouldn't matter as much if there is a TLD collision.

Comment: @jpmc26 and Molot: I agree with Michael.  If the question were instead about binary stars or giant lizards or interstellar commerce, would you think it doesn't belong here?  This would be closed on Writers as "what to write" (as opposed to *how* to write).

Comment: Who cares?  It is fiction.  Registering it is a good idea, to drive sales of the book, of course.  But as long as you do a cursory search to make sure you're not using a child porn site's address or write a bit that says microsoft.com is a site for penis enlargers you can use whatever you want.  Just realize that you will get some feedback about it at some point.  As my father always told me:  Never say anything you couldn't stand seeing in a headline.  I would add that applies double for writing.

Comment: 555 is an invalid phone code? I vaguely remember an advert with the number (555) 555 - 5555 for a law firm. Additionally, you could just register/reserve your own domain to use. having the webspace also lets you add in more world-context that could be hard to implement in a story without expositional dialogue that feels clunky.

Comment: For domain names, the best solution to this is simply to register any domain names you happen to want to use in your story. They honestly don't cost that much, and it means you expand your story with a bit of extra content by making an actual website for it. Loads of potential in that.

Comment: @simba absolutely.  For those unfamiliar, they cost  $ 12/year to register and you can prepay up to 10 years in advance.  Companies charging  10/month are selling a different thing, *web hosting*, and tossing in the domain "for free".  Never take this deal: the web hoster controls your domain and can seize it in any payment dispute, e.g. an unexpected surge of traffic causing a big bandwidth bill. Use different companies for domain registrar vs web hosting.

Comment: @KRyan in fact, one hundred telephone numbers in each area code, **+1 NXX-555-01XX** are indeed formally reserved for use as fictitious numbers in entertainment and advertising by the [North American Numbering Plan Administrator](https://www.nationalnanpa.com/number_resource_info/555_numbers.html).  There are no longer any working 555 numbers other than 555-1212 and the 555 prefix was formally reclaimed in 2016.

Comment: @Michael Ah, thank you. Seems my information was incomplete and out of date.

Answer (score 82):

#### Register a real domain

You could think about registering a **real** domain (with a name relevant to your novel) and then:

- Adding some real content that either is an optional part of the story or
- Adding content that promotes your work.

The following links provide complete instructions on how to register a domain name.

- [How to Register Your Own Domain Name](https://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/registerdomain.shtml)
- [How to Register a Domain Name](http://www.wikihow.com/Register-a-Domain-Name)

---

#### Register a new Top Level Domain

Several comments have suggested creating a new TLD (Top Level Domain). This is **not** recommended because:

- It's nowhere near as easy as registering a second or third level domain and comes with significant extra responsibilities.

  > The application for a new gTLD is a much more complex process. An applicant for a new gTLD is, in fact, applying to create and operate a registry business supporting the Internet's domain name system. This involves a number of significant responsibilities, as the operator of a new gTLD is running a piece of visible Internet infrastructure.
- It is very expensive.

  > The evaluation fee is USD 185,000. Applicants will be required to pay a USD 5,000 deposit fee per requested application slot when registering. The deposit will be credited against the evaluation fee.
  >
  > ...
  >
  > Once an application has successfully passed all the evaluation steps, the applicant is required to sign a New gTLD Agreement (also called Registry Agreement) with ICANN. Under the agreement, there are two fees: (a) a fixed fee of USD 6,250 per calendar quarter; (b) and a transaction fee of USD 0.25. The latter does not apply until and unless more than 50,000 transactions have occurred in the TLD during any calendar quarter or any four calendar quarter period. Please refer to section 6.1 of the New gTLD Agreement in the Applicant Guidebook.

Source [Frequently Asked Questions](https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/applicants/global-support/faqs/faqs-en)

Comment: Creating a top-level domain is  eyond the capability of most individuals.

Comment: @JDługosz Beyond the ability of most individuals, yes, but we don't know what resources the author has at his/her disposal. Or future readers of this question. As for godaddy ads, I've never figured out how a woman's breasts are used in DNS protocols, but I'm sure there's a **man** page for that somewhere.

Comment: @JDługosz I'm proposing a real domain not a TLD.

Comment: So how does that have anything to do with the question, which is about a fictitious TLD?

Comment: @JDługosz The TLd in the question is just a means to an end - making sure that the domain doesn't exist in the real world. This answer provides an alternative: making sure that the domain *does* exist in the real world and that the author has control over its content.

Comment: For a real world example: richardcastle.net used to be a website about the (fictional) author Richard Castle from ABCs series 'Castle'. It now "only" redirects to ABC (since the series has been discontinued), but you can still watch how it looked like: http://web.archive.org/web/20160304215153/http://www.richardcastle.net/

Comment: @Polygnome I read the question as really wanting a fictional TLD because of the alternate history: «so I'd ideally be looking for a TLD I could crowbar into representing that in some way. I did consider .spqr as a sort of equivalent to .gov». He won’t have .com but some latin name instead.  You might add your interpretation as a prelude to your answer.

Comment: @JDługosz You can register a TLD, see here.https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/applicants/global-support/faqs. You would then actually operate that TLD yourself

Comment: @spark I deliberately **did not** suggest that because "An applicant for a new gTLD is, in fact, applying to create and operate a registry business supporting the Internet's domain name system. This involves a number of significant responsibilities, as the operator of a new gTLD is running a piece of visible Internet infrastructure." with a significant cost attached (~$370 for an application).

Comment: @spark. Correction - The costs start at $185,000

Comment: Given the rate at which  TLDs are being added, I would not bet on any TLD being safe.  And the owner of that future TLD could sue you, arguing misuse of their IP if they find you are still selling books after they create the TLD.   The advice "register a real domain" is much wiser.

Comment: I've seen webcomic authors (eg Jeph Jaques and David Willis) use this strategy, and it's worked out pretty well. The urls usually either redirect to the main page or have an extra joke.

Comment: This is how one of my former employer('s sysadmins) solved the problem in real life. We used to have machines with one-word hostnames in our local DNS, available only on the intranet. But then the prospect of gTLDs hove into view, so one-word hostnames are no longer safe against future collisions. Since they were starting a new network from scratch anyway they just registered `.biz` domain for internal use and put everything under it. It had no public DNS records, just on the private DNS server. It's the "right way" if none of the things reserved for private use suits you.

Comment: Not only is there a \$185,000 application fee, there's also \$25,000 per year fee for a gTLD. See https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/applicants/global-support/faqs/faqs-en question 5.7, "Are there any ongoing fees once a gTLD is approved by ICANN?". That might be a bit stiff for many authors.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thx. Answer updated with the extra info.

Answer (score 78):

Several people have suggested the possibility of using real-life reserved domain names. (For those curious, I have a summary of [names and networks reserved for examples and documentation](https://michael.kjorling.se/computers/internet-reservations/examples-and-documentation) on my personal web site.)

Some people have even suggested using real-world domain names that are somehow undesirable, but still valid.

Yet others have suggested to register a domain name of your own, such that you are able to control its content.

I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that **there is a way to make up valid-looking domain names that actually *will not* exist.**

**That's because the two-letter top level domains are ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country or territory codes.** ([ruakh](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2183/ruakh) pointed out in a comment that there exist exceptions to this rule. See below.)

Wikipedia has a handy table of [assignment status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#Decoding_table) of all such code combinations.

There are four ranges that are "free for assignment at the disposal of users" and thus, barring a major rework of the ISO standard, cannot possibly become valid top-level domains. Those are `AA` (just that one), `QM` through `QZ`, `XA` through `XZ` and `ZZ` (just that one).

The same Wikipedia article also has a short list of examples [how some of these are currently being used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#User-assigned_code_elements). There are also a large number of codes [reserved but not free for assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#Reserved_code_elements) for various reasons and varying lengths of time.

**Basically, if you compose a domain name like you normally would on the Internet,**

- but give it a top-level domain out of the ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 "free for assignment at the disposal of users" range, then you can be *all but certain* that it will not clash with any real-world Internet domain name now or in the future.
- but use any of the other ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 reserved combinations for a TLD, then you have to check to make sure that you aren't causing a potential name conflict (for example, `EU` is "exceptionally reserved", and is actually available as a top-level domain), but for the most part you *should* be okay.

So it's perfectly possible for your character to have an email address like `john.doe@momandpopwebmail.qw` and you can be as certain as one can reasonably be that nobody will be registering the domain name `momandpopwebmail.qw` for use on the actual Internet. (Maybe "QW" means "quickweb" in your world?)

### *Always* ISO 3166-1 alpha-2?

As was pointed out by ruakh, citing `.uk` as an example, there are a small number of country-code top-level domains that do not match the country's ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code, which in this case is `GB`.

The criteria for eligibility for a two-letter ccTLD are laid out [by the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA)](https://www.iana.org/help/eligible-tlds). There are a few other exceptional cases allowed for, but the main exception is for ccTLDs that do not match the country's alpha-2 code, but were originally approved before 2000 under an exceptional delegation in ISO 3166 and still maintain that status:

> - Grandfathered prior to 2000. ICANN codified the rules under which future exceptionally reserved delegations may be considered in 2000 in Resolution 00.74. Certain domains were delegated on the basis of being “exceptionally reserved” by the ISO 3166 Maintenance Agency prior to this date. These domains were “.UK”, “.AC”, “.GG” and “.JE”. Of these, “.GG” and “.JE” are now listed in the ISO 3166-1 standard and therefore qualify normally. The remaining two domains that are grandfathered under their original eligibility are “.UK” and “.AC”.

It's worth noting in relation to ruakh's example of the United Kingdom that the Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers (ICANN) lists [`.gb` as "unassigned, reserved" and "originally meant to replace `.uk`"](https://icannwiki.com/CcTLD#Current_ccTLDs). We also note that Wikipedia's summary table lists both `AC` and `UK` as "exceptionally reserved".

Because the rule quoted above is about the eligibility of ccTLDs that were established before the current rules for ccTLD eligibility took effect in year 2000, barring an IANA rule change, *no new ccTLDs can be assigned under the grandfathering criteria.* While not exactly an ISO standard, these rules do on the Internet have status similar to that of an ISO standard.

Since none of the "free for assignment at the disposal of users" ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 codes fall under the grandfathering rule, and no other eligibility criteria appear to apply, **we can still safely use those ranges confident in our assessment that they will not be assigned as top-level domains.**

## What about two-ASCII-letter TLDs not covered by ISO 3166-1 alpha-2?

This is covered by [Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers (ICANN) Resolution 00.74](https://features.icann.org/2000-09-25-delegation-cctlds), which states that (my emphasis):

> It is therefore RESOLVED [00.74] that the IANA staff is advised that **alpha-2 codes not on the ISO 3166-1 list are delegable as ccTLDs only** in cases where the ISO 3166 Maintenance Agency, on its exceptional reservation list, **has issued a reservation of the code** that covers any application of ISO 3166-1 that needs a coded representation in the name of the country, territory, or area involved;

The "advised" is a bit of a red herring here; it means "we are telling you that", not "we are suggesting that". The operative part specifies that "alpha-2 codes not on the ISO 3166-1 list" can be assigned as ccTLDs *only* in the case that said code has a status of "exceptional reservation". As a consequence, the set of TLDs described by "alpha-2 codes" (two English alphabet characters) is restricted to the meaning that those character combinations have in ISO 3166-1 alpha-2.

## But... but... what about in the future?

Sure, things can change. But at this level, things change very slowly. Given how many different entities likely use the "free for assignment at the disposal of users" ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 ranges [for their internal use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#User-assigned_code_elements), were the relevant ISO committee to start to assign those codes for other uses, all hell would break loose. If these codes are ever to be assigned to any other use, there would likely be a *decades-long* transitionary period preceding it. Compare the current [transitional reservations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#Transitional_reservations) which in several cases stretch out to the 2050s, still a good 30-40 years into the future.

Also note that a good half or so of the alpha-2 codes are as of yet *unassigned*. Should [a new country appear](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/25538/6642) tomorrow that is [sufficiently recognized](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/194/6642) to receive its own ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code, it is likely that an appropriate two-letter code could be selected without needing to do anything with the ranges that are specifically available for users' own use.

We also note that [the Frequently Asked Questions for the gTLD application process as published by the ICANN](https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/applicants/global-support/faqs/faqs-en) specifically states that (my emphasis)

> 2.12 Can a New gTLD name be 2 letters?
>
> Applied-for gTLD strings in ASCII must be composed of three or more visually distinct characters. **Two-character ASCII strings are not permitted, to avoid conflicting with current and future country-codes** based on the ISO 3166-1 standard.

On the whole, I wouldn't worry about the risk of collions between future assigned TLDs and the "free for assignment at the disposal of users" ranges in ISO 3166-1 alpha-2. If it ever happens, your story might even become a bit of international relationships history.

## TL;DR:

- Use a two-letter top-level domain of `AA`, `QM` through `QZ`, `XA` through `XZ` or `ZZ`.

Comment: Isn’t that out of date? Or rather, another channel coding on top of that is implied for normally written URLs so that they contain non-ASCII characters now.  In my Answer I assumed this (A-Z only) was still the case for *top level*, but you’re talking about “any part”.

Comment: @JDługosz Internationalized domain names use Punycode encoding with a `xn--` prefix followed by only letters, numbers and hyphens. For example, `bücher.example` is `xn--bcher-kva.example`. Thus the DNS protocol itself is unaffected by internationalized domain names, which made adoption far easier. I'm *pretty* sure that labels beginning with two letters and two hyphens (such as `xn--`) are reserved, but I was unable to locate a reference for that claim so didn't include the suggestion of using that method to construct valid-but-invalid domain names.

Comment: Internationalized top-level domain names have been assigned: see [Internationalized country code top-level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_country_code_top-level_domain). See also [Internationalized domain name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) for a description of how it works in general. Generally speaking, in DNS, the root zone is not special, so you have the same limits (and possibilities) for top-level domains as for labels at any other level.

Comment: Labels certainly can start with digits; current examples include 3m.com and the entirety of in-addr.arpa. I believe [RFC1123](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1123#section-2) first relaxed that definition in 1989.

Comment: @MichaelHomer You are perfectly correct. I have no idea how I could completely forget about `in-addr.arpa`. Fixed!

Comment: If your title gets super popular, some fan of your book make make a momandpopwebmail.qw, for other fans who decide to write to this email to see if it is an easter egg. You could own the website and put an easter egg there yourself. Maybe you put something there that is not revealed in the book, a copy of an email that happened in the book, or it goes to your inbox.

Comment: @GrantDavis Actually registering the domain is the basis for [DavidPostill's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/68798/29). My answer provides a way to make a plausible-looking domain name that (barring major world upheaval) *cannot possibly* exist on the real-world Internet. Both are perfectly valid approaches, and which you choose depends very much on the result you are after.

Comment: All addresses ending in `.aa` looks believable. An an alt-English setting that might stand for "Alpha Authority", the (virtual?) absolute top of the internet name hierarchy instead of lots of gTlds. My Latin isn't up to inventing what aa might mean in an alt-Roman setting.

Comment: @nigel222: altissima auctoritas? I'd still be very slightly concerned that IANA will eventually make one or more of the user-assigned 2-letter codes available as gTLDs. It's true that ISO 3166 promises never to use them as alpha-2 codes, but I'm not sure it follows that ICANN promises never to assign more 2-letter gTLDs which are not ccTLDs.

Comment: @Steve_Jessop as per this answer they are already assigned as ""free for assignment at the disposal of users", which means that there may be one or more organisations out there using them on its internal nameservers for whatever purpose suits them. If it were ever taken away for use externally, all heck would break loose internally. Compare the 192.168. subnet, which is reserved for users, and is now used for the (potentially NAT'ed) IP addresses behind every SoHo router that doesn't use one of the alternatives.

Comment: @nigel222: all heck (well, some amount of heck for some sysadmins) *did* break loose when gTLDs were introduced: exactly what you say would happen with respect to private DNS, did happen. So that's no barrier to IANA. There are several ways listed for a TLD to come into being on the page linked. Being the ISO code of a country is one, but it *doesn't* say that a reserverd 2-letter code is ineligible for any of the other routes (and in particular the gTLD route). Maybe there is some rule that there will never be 2-letter gTLDs, but if so I don't think this answer has found it, is all :-)

Comment: Where by 2-letter I mean 2 ascii letter. There certainly are 2-character gTLDs in other alphabets, for example `.政务`, which of course really is `.xn--zfr164b` in disguise :-) Anyway, my point is that while Michael has cite the rules for "a two-letter ccTLD", he hasn't cited the rules for 2-letter TLDs that are not ccTLDs.

Comment: Here's an example of the reasoning ICANN goes through when it relaxes rules that previously applied. In this case they relaxed the gTLD minimum length requirement from 3 characters to 2 for non-ASCII names, but recommended continuing to forbid 2-character non-ASCII gTLDs that resemble ASCII. So there's a definite difference between "the current rules" and "promises for all time": https://archive.icann.org/en/topics/new-gtlds/idn-3-char-requirement-15feb10-en.pdf

Comment: @SteveJessop See my edit as of now that hopefully addresses your concern.

Comment: @nigel222 *"one or more organisations out there using them on its internal nameservers"* It isn't just about DNS, but lots of other uses as well. Country and territory codes are used in places that aren't readily obvious. Consider that currency symbols are often (always? I can't think of any counterexample off the top of my head.) made up of the two characters of the 3166-1 alpha-2 country code followed by one more character: USD, GBP, EUR, DEM, NOK, ... There are also pseudo-currency-symbols like XAU (gold, Au), XAG (silver, Ag) which match this pattern because XA is reserved for custom use.

Answer (score 42):

As mentioned by @journeyman-geek, you might consider giving your world an alternative name resolution system which avoids collision by not following the format of domain names as seen in our own DNS system. This is easy to imagine as the defining features of modern DNS names (and, by extension, URLs) are largely historical accident.

For example, many email addresses in the *Ender's Game* series look like `hgraff%educadmin@fcom.gov`. A `%` sign in the email address was used by [various network gateways](http://foldoc.org/pub/misc/arpa-hopping) such as the CSNET relay, something which was common at the time the first Ender books were written but is unheard of today.

One such possible scheme could be to reverse the hierarchical order and use colons instead of periods, yielding a format such as `spqr:senate:marcus·tullius·cicero`. (Note also the interpunct, an obscure character in the English alphabet but one which I assume was likely included in basic RSCII and allowed in their DNS names.)

Comment: Along similar lines, consider changing the protocol.  URLs in the WebMage (Ravirn) series are of the form "Mtp://mweb.DecLocus.prime.minus3051/umn.edu" ("M" presumably stands for "multiverse").

Comment: Great idea. In one of William Gibson's cyberpunk stories, I recall a character logging in to a website which was specified in-universe as "fetish:footage:forum" or something like that. Be creative, come up with your own naming system. Robert Columbia, email\rcolu/comsystem-stackoverflow

Comment: The interpunct is an awesome idea!

Comment: AIUI Percent signs in the "user" part of email addresses while discouraged due to historical use are not technically invalid. At least some mailservers are likely to deliver mail to foo%bar@baz.com to the owner of baz.com who can then do with it as they please.

Comment: @PeterGreen Yeah, I looked up the relevant RFCs and was surprised to find just how complex email addresses can get. On the other hand, `vwiggin%Colony1@colmin.gov/citizen` *definitely* isn't valid, and I can't find a historical precedent, either. (Also, people change their email addresses a lot in the Ender universe. How do they keep track?)

Comment: @PeterGreen Generally speaking, SMTP servers are free to interpret the recipient address local-part as they please (and relay SMTP servers are specifically prohibited from mangling it; [RFC 5321 § 2.3.11](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-3.6.1), for example). Some special characters were used early on to do things like enable routing between different mail systems; for example, SMTP and UUCP.

Comment: I really like this idea. Domains could be as long or as short as needed. USA:NY:NYC:Donald·John·Trump would tell the network to get that Donald instead of the Donald J. Trump in (for example) Portland, OR. It could be expanded to stars and planets (SOL:Earth:USA:NY:NYC), or shortened to only locations near me (Fargo:NDSU), or used to find businesses (CA:Ontario:Toronto:Hotels) or a specific business (CA:Ontario:Toronto:Sheraton·Toronto·Airport·Hotel).

Comment: That should be `spqr:senatus:marcus·tullius·cicero` but it's not enough of an edit for me to be able to do it myself.

Comment: @wolfgang: `vwiggin%Colony1@colmin.gov/citizen` isn't a valid email address, but it's not hard to imagine a URI scheme that's *similar* to the `mailto:` scheme except that it has been brought into line with other URI schemes like `http:` by including a "path" component (perhaps for the use of the recipient for mail filtering?). Then this would be a URI in that scheme, with its scheme sheared off. I'm not saying OSC *did* imagine this, just that an excuse along those lines could probably work. And it's not the best possible explanation of why the path would be `/citizen` ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop I've just asked http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151020/what-is-the-format-of-ender-universe-email-addresses

Comment: Regarding reversing the order of the labels, that was done on Usenet (where, for example, `sci` was subdivided into `sci.astronomy`, `sci.space` and so on; thus looking roughly like a reversal of DNS names), and on FidoNet (where you would have an address like `1:234/999.12345` where `1` specified the continent, `234` the area, `999` a system, and `12345` (optional) specified a user connected to that system). A long time ago, back in the glory days, I had a FidoNet address of `2:201/204.4` -- I remember that I specifically asked the owner of the node 2:201/204 for a low point number.

Answer (score 13):

Nothing that would really work - as per bob's excellent comment, there's a list of reserved, example TLDs, none of which are suitable and the new gTLDs are pretty broad.

There's nothing stopping a organisation with a justification and enough money from registring any new gTLD.

Its worth considering the rich and varied tradition of *making things up* when talking about computers in media, from interfaces to websites.

As such the 'clever' way would be to introduce some slight, subtle inconsistancy.

555 was picked so it wouldn't route to any phone number

You could simply pick a branch of the multiverse where things went differently, colons instead of dots, or even having your network as one large set of directories.

So the office of the imperitor general of the imperial sanitation department might be at spqr/sanitation/org/official/imperitor.

This would break in any modern web browser and would be consistant.

Or just gloss it over and tell, don't show.

Comment: If you had directories, the TLDs would be at the top - so `org/sanitation/spqr/official/imperitor`, rather than `spqr/sanitation/org/official/imperitor`.

Comment: Its late, and I was completely making this up as I go along. ;p

Comment: With that in mind, you don't even need directories for the domains, you can still use periods and not have it conflict with any website: org.sanitation.spqr/official/imperitor

Comment: @Miguel that's what the OP wanted to avoid in case `spqr` becomes a valid TLD at some point.

Comment: @Bob You are right, I meant to say that subdomains would use the place now used for TLDs, it's easier to picture if we use `.www`: `spqr.sanitation.www/official/imperitor`

Comment: Great point suggesting to "tell, don't show". "Brutus hastily typed in the website address of the Imperial Roman Zoo Inspection Service that had been written on the back of the pizza receipt, swearing under his breath about the awkward keyboard that the machines of Londinium usually had." The fewer details you give, the fewer details there are that can become out of date. Let your readers decide what a Roman Zoo Inspection Service website address looks like and what might have been awkward about Londinium keyboards.

Answer (score 7):

There is the tTLD (test top-level domain) class of domains, like `.test` (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.test or [RFC 6761 from February 2013, section 6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761#section-6.2)), the same in various scripts and common languages for that script (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain#IDN_test_domains).

[RFC 2606 from June 1999, section 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606#section-2) also mentions `.test` and additionally:

- `.example`
- `.invalid`
- `.localhost`

with the following explanation:

> ```
>   ".test" is recommended for use in testing of current or new DNS
> ```

```
  related code.
```

> ```
>   ".example" is recommended for use in documentation or as examples.
> ```

> ```
>   ".invalid" is intended for use in online construction of domain
> ```

```
  names that are sure to be invalid and which it is obvious at a
  glance are invalid.
```

> ```
>   The ".localhost" TLD has traditionally been statically defined in
> ```

```
  host DNS implementations as having an A record pointing to the
  loop back IP address and is reserved for such use.  Any other use
  would conflict with widely deployed code which assumes this use.
```

Comment: That list of test names is specifically not of interest to the OP!  It needs to be realistic in his context, not obviously a testing name.

Comment: To future authors: please don't pick any of those TLDs.

Comment: One could retcon the meaning of one or more of these domains. For example, ".test" could be defined within the story to be an acronym of "Trans-European State Territory", a formal name for a political entity existing within the universe. Similarly, one could observe that the word "host" can also mean "army", so ".localhost" could be defined as as top level domain name for "local" (e.g. as opposed to regional or national) military installations, forts, etc.

Comment: Going with my "localhost" idea, the centurion in charge of the western half of Hadrian's Wall might be addressed in the network as "centurion@hadrian-occidental.britannica.localhost".

Comment: As a software guy myself, "localhost" is heavily ingrained as a special identifier with a specific meaning, and it would be very difficult to maintain the fiction. The word "test" could plausibly be used, as above, but still only with great care.

Answer (score 7):

## If your world allows, your world's Internet doesn't work the same.

If you create your Internet to use underscores, a certain character, or a character you invented instead of a period, then you can have whatever address (if your new Internet uses addresses) you want.

Or you could do away with top and sub domains all together. For example you could have John Doe's email address be:

```
John-doe@email
```

And have the search engine address be:

```
websearch
```

This is pretty future proof, because top and sub domains aren't going anywhere.

Those were some ideas, you could get creative with your new Internet.

Answer (score 4):

As part of the general idea of making something that would not be a legal TLD (as o.m. notes), you could have a character not found in ASCII as part of the TLD.  The [development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Latin_alphabet#Historical_development) turned out a little different in your universe.

This could work especially well if the alternate history skipped something that was responsible for one of our modern letters, so *of course* that would be different.

Using a real (historical) letter has the advantage of being able to type and print it: (Þ, þ) is one of my favorites. Or maybe they kept some that look more like the Greek progenitors (Γ instead of C) or G is still a C with diacritical mark.

I think it would be interesting if one such change were present in names and such; not so much as to baffle the reader, but just one difference to give it a unique character [pun intended].

With internationalized domain names now, *mixing* scripts from different languages (like using Γ for C but otherwise Latin characters) is unlikely to match any future domain name, which will be in one language or the other but not mix languages in the same word.

If the book is self-published and you’re providing print-ready PDF, you could make your own unique character. But it’s quite hard to invent something suitable as a letter that’s not already real (and hopefully in Unicode).

Much of the URI syntax is “just the way it turned out” and it could easily have been different.  I recall reading that Tim Berners-Lee considers the current system inconsistent with the hostname backwards from the path, and use of different separators is unnecessary.  So `www.example.com/site/page#fragment` should really be `com.example.www.site.page.fragment`.  Point is, in an alternate history you will **expect** the syntax to be different in detail, even if they hit upon the same general idea of a uniform resource locator as a hiarchy that extends a machine’s directory structure.

You might use a different (or different *looking*) character as the separator, such as a tiny superscript `^` or a vertical bar that spans the whole ascender through decender height of the character cell.

Comment: They would be possible in i18n domain names. You would need to do so in a TLD which doesn't include those characters in their whitelist.

Comment: TLD is what I’m referring to.

Comment: I like this idea :Þ

Comment: The letter þ is very much in use. Compare [Eyþór Ingi Gunnlaugsson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ey%C3%BE%C3%B3r_Ingi_Gunnlaugsson), an Icelandic singer who participated in the Eurovision Song Contest 2013 with the song *Ég á líf*.

Comment: I'd suggest replacing the periods and--if applicable--the at-sign with some other character.  For example `james~kirk≗enterprise≛starfleet≛ufp`.  That should avoid any conflict with actual addresses even if there were an actual `ufp` domain.

Comment: To facilitate the most efficient annoyance generation, invent some new glyphs instead of using using existing ones.  That way you annoy the geeks trying to register domains like your book, readers trying to explain/pronounce them, the publisher who has to print the thing, your editing software that has to make sense of it, and you for having to type it in.  Efficiency!

Comment: @supercat: specifically I think the `~` avoids it, I don't think that's allowed in a domain label. If not for that, someone could (in principle) register the whole thing as a gTLD and use it as a dotless hostname.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the system most countries that are not the USA use. Combining the TLD for the purpose of the website with the country's TLD

For example the website for the praetorian guard would be: `www.praetorian-guard.gov.rom` or  `www.praetorian-guard.gov.spqr` while a normal website would be along the lines of `www.pizza.com.rom` or `www.pizza.com.spqr`.

That way, even if the TLD `.spqr` or `.rom` are registered as a gTLD, the websites would not exist because such format is only used for regular TLDs. And it's not like a new country will just appear and claim `.spqr` or `.rom` anytime soon, if ever.

Comment: Note that any TLD can be now created by a (well-endowed) company or entity. For example: `.run`, `.room`, `.sony`, and `.alpharomeo` are all actual TLDs today.

Comment: If `.spqr` were registered as a gTLD, wouldn't that allow the owner of `.spqr` to register (or sell to someone else) the domain name `com.spqr`, allowing someone to get `pizza.com.spqr` as a subdomain?

Comment: @TannerSwett: yes, if the gTLD operator wants to. As it happens, there's 130 TLDs with `com` as a public suffix immediately under them: `com.ac`, `com.af`, `com.ag`, etc. At the moment all of them are country(-like) TLDs, but I don't think it's out of the question for a gTLD operator to do the same. Really it's just a matter of whether they think there's demand for `yournamehere.com.spqr`: if so then they can put in place a system to register such names. It would be bad luck for the author who used it as a "fake" domain name, but avoiding such bad luck is what name registration is all about!

Answer (score 3):

How about something that would not be a valid domain name, but looks roughly like one?

.sen_rome

.r

Reserved ones are things like .test or .invalid, they stand out in a story.

Answer (score 2):

FYI Rome's actual institutional website domains are:

- `www.comune.roma.it` (literally"common".rome.it)
- `www.cittametropolitanaroma.gov.it` (lit. "metropolitan city of rome".gov.it)

I live there & I would incredibly love to see the '.spqr' in such a story. Anyways, I don't believe that domain name will ever be added (never say never: angry spanish people got `.cat` domain).

Anyways consider this: if the Roman Empire survived 2300 years they would have developed other ways to describe domains. But, because you are the author and people (or nerds?) expect a normal-looking domain name you could just flip the entire name like java packages or similar dot-separated syntax.

There would not be an international standard as the emperor ands senators would have it very roman-centric, i think maybe a sort of directory-like nomenclature for websites, where every website would be given an unique domain name by the Pontifex (or his office).

There would be an hyper textum translationis protocollum using that to fetch resources for users.

For example one of the few approved search engines, the Google Indagator, is reachable here: `http://spqr.indagator.google`. Here is Ceasar's memorial website: `http://spqr.historia.caesar`.

As romans sought to integrate other people in the empire they would eventually add something like: `http://spqr.barbari.carthago.voluptuaria` for websites about external countries (this specific one to have a family trip to the ruins of a famous city in Tunisia).

Comment: Note that `.google` is a real, existing, TLD. And the domain name [`com.google`](https://com.google) exists.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a single-letter second-level domain in .com, .net, or .org, like y.com, or 1.org. There is more info on which TLDs won’t accept these in the Wikipedia article “[Single-letter second-level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-letter_second-level_domain)”.

Another option would be to make up your own addressing scheme like:

```
<info-link#info-provider:some-company:blah>
```

Comment: @Anketam. There was actually text there but the Markdown formatting hid it by mistake. I've edited to make it visible.

Answer (score 1):

a.com, b.com, c.com, etc.

> In 1993, the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) explicitly reserved all single-letter and single-digit second-level domain names in the top-level domains com, net, and org

Some were reserved before '93 and do actually have sites (i.net, q.com, q.net, x.com, x.org, z.com, a.co, g.co, t.co, t.me, w.org), but everything else is off limits.

However...

> In December 2005, ICANN considered auctioning these domains

So maybe these domains will be available someday. But it's been 11 years, so I wouldn't bite my nails about it.

Source: [Single-letter second-level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-letter_second-level_domain)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something quite different, like sort-of an X.400 address with different labels:  nun=incudibus,dpca=acme,dap=com

Answer (score 1):

### There are reserved IP addresses

For example, 127.0.0.1 routes back to your own computer, while 192.168.XXX.XXX addresses are reserved for internal use in private networks, as are the 10.XXX.XXX.XXX and 172.16.XXX.XXX blocks. You can safely use them as fictional addresses knowing that no-one on the internet has these addresses.

There are also some IP blocks reserved for documentation, namely 192.0.2.XXX, 198.51.100.XXX and 203.0.133.XXX.

IPv6 has the block 2001.bd8.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX reserved for documentation, while fcXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX is for use in private networks.

Unfortunately they're not quite as punchy as domain names, although you can actually connect to IP addresses through your browser.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses

https://michael.kjorling.se/computers/internet-reservations/examples-and-documentation

Comment: All the media I've seen which uses IP addresses as part of a dramatisation fudges the numbers so they're out of range (e.g. 324.192.87.44)

Comment: Actually, those aren't so much *reserved* as *specially assigned*. (It wasn't always this way. NET-10, for example, IIRC was originally used for ARPANET administrative purposes, and was very much routable.) However, there are several blocks that are actually reserved specifically for *examples and documentation*. On my personal web site I have a list of [Internet names and networks reserved for examples and documentation](https://michael.kjorling.se/computers/internet-reservations/examples-and-documentation) which you may find useful. I made it because the info is spread out in several RFCs.

Comment: @Michael Kjörling : Thanks. I'll link that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there are any reserved names for authors. I know that Microsoft reserved some fictitious names themselves so perhaps that is a good example of what others do.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061013-05/?p=29393

Comment: Hello and welcome to worldbuilding.SE! Maybe you could flesh out your answer a little bit, e.g. by taking the examples from that site, explaining where microsoft uses their fake-name and how this could be applied to the problem described in the question. Answers that mainly consist of a likn are rarely well received, especially because a link could be outdated at some point. If you want you can take the [tour](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and view the [help center](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about how answers and questions should be written.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this in 2022 and it occured to me that the trends of cctlds have changed a bit since 2017. For example, there is now .scot, .wales, .quebec, and .cat. So for a theoretical a modern day Rome a cctld of .spqr wouldn't be that odd after all.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_top-level_domain